# Getting hebrew character from http response in json on android

Tags: android, json, encoding

I'm working on a project in which I need to get some data from my app engine server which contains hebrew characters (the data is sent in json).

**On server side:**

```
resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
out.print(responeData.toString());
```

when I'm debugging the server I see that the response data seems fine (meaning, it's showing my hebrew characters.

**On the client side (android):**

After executing this code, the resultData i'm getting is with ??? instead hebrew characters.
I tried all different encodings such as 'windows-1255', 'iso-8859-8' 
Does anyone knows what the problem is?
Thanks!

```
// Create new default http client
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout Limit
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000);
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(serviceURL);

    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(requestPayload.toString());
        post.addHeader(CustomHeader.TASK_NAME.getHeaderName(), taskName);
        se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);

        // Execute the request
        response = client.execute(post);

        // Get the response status code
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

        if (statusCode == 200) { // Ok
            if (response != null) { // Checking response
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); // Get the data in the entity
                retreturnVal = HttpCaller.readContentFromIS(in);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error in connectivity layer, stacktrace: ", e.toString());
        return null;
    }

    public static String readContentFromIS(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();       
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `ServletResponse` on your server, instead of calling

```
resp.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

you should call

```
resp.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

This should have the effect of changing the encoding used in the call to `getWriter()` to UTF-8. I don't think that calling `setHeader` has the same side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I did

```
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(requestPayload.toString(), "UTF-8");
```

instead of

```
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity(requestPayload.toString());
```

and it works fine for me, it's another solution.